# Get parameters from router with Meteor and iron:router

Tags: node.js, meteor, iron-router, meteor-helper

I have a route

```
Router.route('/post/:_id', {
  name: 'post',
  template: 'post'
});
```

and a helper

```
Template.post.helpers({
  post: function () {
    return Posts.findOne(this._id);
  }
});
```

It wont find the specified post. But I guess I'm getting the id in a wrong way. I've seen some projects where they have used sessions. Is this really necessary? Isn't it possible to get the parameters from the router?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you'd set the data context at the route level like this :

```
Router.route("/post/:_id",{
  name:"post",
  template:"post",
  waitOn:function(){
    return this.subscribe("post",this.params._id);
  },
  data:function(){
    return Posts.findOne(this.params._id);
  }
});
```

In `RouteController` methods you can access the URL parameters using `this.params.parameterName`.

Then in your post template you can access the data context set by the router without the need of a dedicated helper.

```
<template name="post">
  post id is {{_id}}
</template>
```

As far as the posts list is concerned, you can stick to the same pattern :

```
Router.route("/posts",{
  name:"posts",
  template:"posts",
  waitOn:function(){
    return this.subscribe("posts");
  },
  data:function(){
    return {
      posts:Posts.find()
    };
  }
});

<template name="posts">
  {{#each posts}}
    {{> postItem}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: Great! What about my post list? Should it still be setted as helpers? `Template.posts.helpers({ posts: function () { return Posts.find(); } });`

Comment: Edited my post to give my insight on this.

Answer (score 0):

It is more organized to have all your data fetching points in helpers. So you can do this:

**routes.js**

```
Router.route('/post/:_id', {
    name: 'post',
    template: 'post'
});
```

**post.js**

```
Template.post.helpers({
    post: function() {
        var postId = Router.current().params._id;
        return Posts.findOne({_id: postId});
    }
});
```

*Remember that if you are not subscribing (posts) in any other file, you can subscribe in router itself:*

**routes.js** (with subscription)

```
Router.route('/post/:_id', {
    name: 'post',
    template: 'post',
    waitOn: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe('posts');
    }
});
```

**Update:**

`Router.current().params._id` seems to have an issue, it'll return all the Id's for that route previously ran.

*So restructured way should be (example from my app):*

**route.js**

```
Router.route('/play/:gameId', {
    name: 'play',
    template: 'gamesPlay',
    waitOn: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe('games');
    },
    onBeforeAction: function() {
        Session.set('gameId', this.params.gameId);
        console.log('game id set '+Session.get('gameId'));
        this.next();
    },
    onStop: function() {
        // do something when user navigate away from this route
    }
});
```

**games.js**

```
Template.gamesPlay.helpers({
    game: function() {
        var gameId = Session.get('gameId'); //instead of Router.current().params.gameId;
        var game = Games.findOne({_id: gameId});
        return game;
    }
});
```

Comment: I think I agree that it's more organized but saimeunt says that data usually is set in the router. Have Meteor mentioned some preferred way to do it? I will also make sense to have waitOn and data fetching points at the same place in the code.

Comment: @Jamgreen added waitOn example. I think subscriptions are more like broad data points, so we can have it in router and forget. But for particular data variables which we use in the view, its better to put in helpers itself (easier for other developers to find as they will be looking at the helper file first).

Comment: What if I want to use `postId` in multiple functions inside the helpers? Will it be OK to set `var postId = Router.current().params._id;` above `Template.post.helpers({`?

Comment: Anything outside `Template.post.helpers({` will not be reactive i guess.